# is it possible to get collection of types what form the union?

Tags: julia

Let's say I have the `Union`:

```
    SomeUnion = Union{Int, String}
```

Is there a method to extract a collection of types that form this union? For example ....

```
    union_types(SomeUnion) # => [Int, String]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just write down a simple example here:

```
a = Union(Int,String)

function union_types(x)
  return x.types
end

julia> union_types(a)
(Int64,String)
```

you can store the result into an array if you want:

```
function union_types(x)
    return collect(DataType, x.types)
end

julia> union_types(a)
2-element Array{DataType,1}:
 Int64 
 String
```

UPDATE: use `collect` as @Luc Danton suggested in comment below.

Comment: `collect(DataType, a.types)` can be a concise way to, well, collect the types into an array.

Comment: @LucDanton using  `collect` is so elegant!  I've updated my answer as you suggested.

Comment: this solution not work now

Answer (score 4):

For Julia 0.6, NEWS.md states that "`Union` types have two fields, `a` and `b`, instead of a single `types` field". Additionally, "Parametric types with "unspecified" parameters, such as `Array`, are now represented as `UnionAll` types instead of `DataType`s".

Thus, to get the types as a tuple, one can do

```
union_types(x::Union) = (x.a, union_types(x.b)...)
union_types(x::Type) = (x,)
```

If you want an array, just `collect` the tuple

```
julia> collect(union_types(Union{Int, Float64, String, Array}))
4-element Array{Type,1}:
 Int64  
 Float64
 String
 Array
```

Answer (score 2):

`Base.uniontypes` is not documented (as of `julia-1.6.1`), so use with care.
But it works:

```
julia> SomeUnion = Union{Int, String}
Union{Int64, String}

julia> Base.uniontypes(SomeUnion)
2-element Vector{Any}:
 Int64
 String
```